# Disk space monitor - where did my disk space go?

Tags: windows, file-management, disk-analysis

I've been using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) for years to graphically show what directories take up the space on my disk, but that doesn't answer a very simple question:

> I suddenly have 1Gb less space than yesterday. Where did that space go!?

Is there some Windows tool that can take snapshots periodically, then diff them to show what directories grew in size?

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have? If you have Windows 8.1, it could be related to the latest big update (that Microsoft forced down your throat)

Comment: @nidunc: Windows 7, but the problem is general, space suddenly disappears after... events I can't quite pinpoint. Browser caches getting fat? Windows updates being installed? The only things that I *can* pinpoint are downloads and copying media in.

Answer (score 11):

## [Xinorbis](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xinorbis-and-tools/) (moved from [the original site](http://web.archive.org/web/20210211100623/http://xinorbis.com/)) might be what you're looking for

It has a simple GUI, for better or worse, but it includes the capability to store an archive of the folder/file history from your periodic snapshots (By default it integrates with SQlite 3).

*A screenshot showing a graph of how a folder has changed over time:*
[image: Xinorbis]

Answer (score -2):

[Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) has a nice gui

Very small size - only 500KB

It's freeware.

[image]

Comment: +0.  Does it let you see how the size of a folder has changed over time?

Comment: This tool only shows the disk space usage, but can't compare snapshots or track it over time.