# A way to view the largest directories

Tags: windows, file-management

A while back, I had a nifty program that displayed subdirectory size, using larger squares for large ones and smaller squares for small ones. Something interactive like that would be good, or maybe a list of the largest subdirectories in a directory.

I'm running out of hard drive space and I'm looking for things I don't need any more.

Comment: What program did you use at the past? What things did unnecessary things mean?

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/disk-space-usage-utilization-analysis-for-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many such programs, the original was [Sequoia view](http://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview/)

Here's the

[image]

"displayed subdirectory size, using larger squares for large ones and smaller squares for small ones"; note that you can also colo(u)r code file types.

For more possibiliites, see https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-space-analyzer.htm or https://alternativeto.net/software/spacemonger/

I will admit that I prefer to use [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) :

[image]

Comment: If you prefer WinDirStat, why did you bother mentioning SequoiaView? Or at least why didn't you lead with WinDirStat? If you're going to bother mentioning SequoiaView, why not also mention KDirStat? Both of those were [inspirations for WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/background.html).

Comment: A fair enough point. It was my belief that Sequioa View was the original, and for many years it was all that I knew. I guess that I expected the reader to read all the way to the end & put he conclusion there, after offering a few alternatives. Of course, I only expressed a personal preference, without giving reasons, and YMMV. I gave a few examples which answer the question, but, at the end of the day, it's up to the reader to decide which they prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Disk Space Fan can be helpful. It shows folders and subfolders' size using pictorial diagram (all folders and subfolders are sorted by size). You can see how much space a folder occupies. It's freeware, too. Also try Folder Size if you want Windows Explorer-style disk analyzer tool.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but the interface seems hard to use.

Comment: Could you please googling for your wanted software that also user friendly?

Answer (score 0):

[WizTree](https://www.diskanalyzer.com/) is free, fast, portable and has some great features:

[image]